# How to pull an item from the set of elements using capybara with rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I've tried to refactor the old piece of tests. The code below:

```
describe "translation result", :js => true do
  it "translations should be shown as links to translations in second way" do
    visit '/'
    fill_in('query-field', :with => 'kOŃ')
    click_button('search-button')

   sleep(7)
   page.all(:css, '.result a').size.should eq(2)
   page.find('.result a').text.should == 'horse'
  end
end
```

return information below:

```
1) translation result translations should be shown as links to translations in second way
 Failure/Error: page.find('.result a').text.should == 'horse'
 Capybara::Ambiguous:
   Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching css ".result a"
 # ./spec/integration/result_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I tried to get a element from what is returned by 'find method' in describe block. It means I tried to do it as below shown:

```
page.find('.result a').first.text.should == 'horse'
```

or

```
page.find('.result a')[0].text.should == 'horse'
```

I did it because I think when I got two elements then I can get one of them. Do you think my logic is correct ? How to resolve the problem. The repo with code is here: **https://github.com/mtczerwinski/dict-app**

Comment: did you try `page.all(:css, '.result a').first.text.should == 'horse'` ?

Comment: `page.should have_css('.result a', text: 'horse', match: :first)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capybara Ambiguity Resolution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132506/capybara-ambiguity-resolution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `all` in place of `find` if you really want to find multiple matches:

```
page.all('.result a').first.text.should == 'horse'
```

See http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#all-instance_method